# Display X & Y Value of Selected row/cell in a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have created a HTML table with clickable cells (td) within that table (Similar to Excel)

I have an input field (read only)

```
<input type="text" readonly="">
```

I want to display the coordinates of where the user is clicked when they click on the table in this input field.

For example if a user is clicked on a cell which corresponds on X axis to Name 2 and Y axis to 16, then I want the input field to say "Name 2 | 16"

It is a reference display so the users can see what they are clicked on in a cluttered grid. Excel does this when u click on any cell within Excel.

I have created a jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/37PGT/

Looking for some assistance.

Comment: Is it just me or are we unable to see the source for the fiddle link?  I just see the end product, nothing in the html/js/css boxes!?

Comment: @Kami It is working fine for me.

Comment: you have to refresh it a couple of times

Comment: @Kami jsFiddle had a massive update last week - you need to clear your cache to see the updates.

Comment: Cool, thanks. A hard refresh did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `id` of `cellRef` to the `input`, then in your `mouseup` handler add this code:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;
var cell = $(this).index();
$('#cellRef').val(row + ' | ' + cell);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/37PGT/2/)

To get the label of the row (so you can format the input to be `Name 1 | 1`, use this line to set `row`:

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
```

Comment: Rory, thanks for your answer. thats great. I am wondering is there any way to actually pull in the text from column 1 instead of the numerical number? For example if I click the selected cell in your example "1 | 1" I was intending that to read "Name 1 | 01"

Comment: really awesome. thanks a lot. Need to wait 4 more mins to accept answer, then I click it...cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well I can suggest the following:

```
var rowIndex= jQuery.ArrayIn($(this).parent(),$('#tableID tr'));
var columnIndex=jQuery.ArrayIn($(this),$(this).parent().children('td'));
```

It may be possible that your script would become busy for such operation. *I rather would recommend you that you store your custom attribute such as row Number and column number on each **`<td>`** and that would even make your operation not only easy but also scale-able to provide much more functionality than just selection.*